# Various ways to handle timing in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, handler, countdown

I have a need for a very simplistic way to keep track of time.  Basically I simply need to start a timer when a method is called, and a set amount of time after that (45-90 seconds) call another method.

From what I have read, Handlers are the most efficient way to handle keeping track of time.  However, some say they require a second thread, while others say they don't.  It's certainly not a huge deal, but I would prefer to keep things as minimalistic as possible.  So, is there any way to do something like simply checking to see if System.getCurrentTimeMillis is a certain amount higher than it was when the user called the first method, without any further user interaction of course.

If not I will just read into Handlers more and work with those.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: "Basically I simply need to start a timer when a method is called, and a set amount of time after that (45-90 seconds) call another method" -- um, that's not quite enough information. Who is "I"? An Activity? A Service? You don't care? Will the activity (or whatever) be guaranteed to be around for the 45-90 seconds? Or should the timer still go off if, say, an activity started it and the user pressed the BACK button? Rather than giving us vague generic technical descriptions, you will be better served giving us the actual user scenario, so we can give you more accurate advice.

Comment: I apologize for being a tad indirect, I didn't think a very detailed explanation was required for this.  This is all within an activity.  The very basic idea behind this is hiding a view, and then reshowing that view after a set amount of time.  Should the user navigate away somewhere that would make this pointless, I would simply cut the timer off and take care of the resulting loose ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call your first method you call the second method after 90 seconds with:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //here call the second method

            }   

}, 90000);
```

However, if the user clicks on return and leave the activity, this postdelayed runnable will restart the activity, hence you need to put an if statement in it to check if that activity is still running...

If you need to monitor how much time has passed every 1 second before the timer has ended then you can use this code

```
new CountDownTimer(90000, 1000) { 

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
        //call to my UI thread every one second 
    } 

    public void onFinish() { 
        //final call to my UI thread after 90 seconds
    } 
 }.start();
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed this in my search, but this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure about the restart Activity thing. If the user leaves the Activity, it won't typically be destroyed, only paused or stopped. Then the Handler will call the run() method even though your Activity isn't visible, which might or might not be what the OP wants. If the Activity was destroyed, then the Handler is gone (AFAIK it is bound to the Context) and the method won't be called.

Comment: I've tested it on my application. I start the application and a postDelayed method starts another activity in 5 seconds. If I leave the application just after launching it, the second activity still starts after few seconds on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a TimerTask and the method postDelayed. For a good description see here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html