# Fade in Fade out Animation on different ImageViews with in a table layout sequentially?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, tablelayout

I have a table layout with 3 rows and 3 columns. In total I have 9 ImageViews with set backgrounds. All these imageviews are initially hidden but making it invisible. I have method for performing a fade-in fade-out animation. It is working fine when I call my animation function on one imageview. However if I call the animation function from a for loop, all the imageviews are being animated simultaneously. I need this to happen sequentially.

E.g. for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
startanimation(imageViews[i]);
}

void startanimation(){
 Do fade in fade out on the given imageview
working fine on one image
}

NOTE: I have declared an array of imageViews so I need not use java reflection to access imageviews dynamically.

int[] imageViews = {R.id.ImageView01,  R.id.ImageView02, R.id.ImageView03, R.id.ImageView04, R.id.ImageView05, R.id.ImageView06, R.id.ImageView07, R.id.ImageView08, R.id.ImageView09}

I have tried Thread.sleep(xxx) and also handlers but still not able to achieve my objective. Basically if I send the imageview position and an image to the startanimation(), it should fadein fade out that image at that imageview location and return to the main activity ONLY after completing the whole animation. Right now it **seems** like it is returning only after completing fadein fadeout animation on all the iamgeviews. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in my game.
First you need to store all buttons into a map:

```
private Map<Integer, Button> buttonViews = new HashMap<Integer, Button>();
```

Then when you create buttons add them all into the map:

```
buttonViews.put(0, myButton);
```

Then you need to call a recursive method showButtons(0) like

```
showButtons(int button){

//set button visible
buttonViews.get(button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//set button animation
 Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyActivity.this, R.anim.fadeIn);
 buttonViews.get(button).startAnimation(myAnim);

//then use onAnimationEnd
myAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation...
```

In onAnimationEnd call showButtons(button++)
When all buttons are exhausted break this recursive loop.
If you need to make a further delay between each animation then you can use postdelay method: [Various ways to handle timing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910929/various-ways-to-handle-timing-in-android/4911609#4911609) inside of onAnimationEnd

Comment: I tried something very similar to the above but the behavior is very unstable. I do not get any error messages or the program does not crash when I recursively call my startanimation() method on animation end. However not all of my images are displayed. Only a few images fade in and fade out and then I see the following message in LogCat window: Launch Timeout has expired, giving up wake up Lock!

Comment: My method works perfectly in my game, using scale animations. I think you should give it a try again and experiment. It sounds something is wrong with looping like it never stops. Post your code if you need help.

Comment: Thank you very much for you patience and quick response. I am trying to implement using hashmaps like you suggested. However, I wanted to let you know what I am witnessing with my current code. I am testing using emulator. It looks like my activity is going in to sleep mode some how without completing all the animation. If I click on the home button, the control goes to home screen. IF I press and hold home button again to show previously launchde apps and select my app, the program reloads and completes from where it left off and completes the whole animation. Something is timingout

Comment: I don't have much experince with emulators they are too slow for any serious work especially animations and games. You can try a different version emulator like 2.1, 2.2 or 2.3... see if there is any difference.

Comment: This looked like an emulator issue. I did not try to debug it further.My original code works fine on a real handset. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using `myAnim.setStartOffset(buttonIndex*animDuration)` ?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to fade each image individually, then you will have to have a timer for each of the images. Right now, you have only one timer.

Or else you will have to keep a table of the images and fade each one when the previous image is completely faded. That is, make an outer loop to keep track of which image is being faded now and increment the image pointer -- that is, go to the next image -- when the current image is all done fading.

HTH. It sounds complicated, but really it's not. In the loop, just don't touch any other image than the one you are currently fading.

-- pete

Comment: @ Pete - Would you please give me a sample code the outer loop?

Comment: @dev -- Hmmmm. If I'd looked more closely at your code, I'd have seen that you are doing exactly what I'm recommending already: for(int i=0;i<9;i++){ startanimation(imageViews[i]); }  So it looks like you have to start debugging startanimation( image ) to find out what it thinks it should be fading and how it should return -- either after an image is completely faded; or else after an image fade has started. If startanimation( ) returns right after the fade has started, then you have to find out what the flag is that says "fade is complete for this image" and loop on that. Reasonable?